# Costs of running WhatsApp in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, whatsapp

So I know there is a quota of supermessages that we need to purchase to run campaigns out of SFMC and consume them according to the multipliers. But what about the meta side? Are there any additional costs billed on meta side as well on top of the supermessages within SFMC? Do we need to keep a line of credit there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can no longer use same supermessages for WhatsApp and SMS as for rest of SFMC. These credits are now specific to these channels.

The model for WhatsApp is quite complex, as it is a combination of message type as well as recipients country.

Salesforce will be paying for these messages to Meta, and this cost is covered as part of the above message consumption. No additional costs will be billed directly to you by Meta.

The details can be found on [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000395196&language=en_US&type=1), with the multipliers listed [here](https://www.salesforce.com/products/marketing-cloud/sfmc/sms-ratio-updates/).

Comment: Hi Lukas, thanks for response. However I'm quite familiar with SFMC billing me for the WA messages sent, what I don't understand is whether per each such message Meta will charge me as well? do I need to keep a line of credit on the business manager account? Or SFMC somehow accounts for meta costs within the supermessages cost?

Comment: @user145545 my bad. Missed that part. I have updated my reply

Comment: Thanks a lot, glad to know that!